# Word counter for a nested dictionary and a list

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a dictionary that looks like this:

```
d = {'name1': {'details': ['something',
   'another thing',],
  'groups': ['first', 'second'],
 },
'name2': {'details': ['other details'],
  'groups': ['first', 'third'],
 }}
```

And a list that looks like this:

```
groups = ['first', 'second', 'third']
```

I would like to count how many times each group is mentioned and get the following output:

```
counted = {'first': 2, 'second':1, third:1}
```

I have tried loops, but getting various errors.

Comment: Your `groups` list isn't a list. It's a tuple (of lists).

Comment: @jarmod, thanks - typo :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should do it

```
import itertools
from collections import Counter
Counter(itertools.chain.from_iterable([x['groups'] for x in d.values()]))
```

Output

```
Counter({'first': 2, 'second': 1, 'third': 1})
```

Answer (score 3):

You can do it with `list comprehension` :

```
from collections import Counter
print(Counter([i for v in d.values() for i in v["groups"]]))
# Counter({'first': 2, 'second': 1, 'third': 1})
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
        d = {'name1': {'details': ['something',
   'another thing',],
  'groups': ['first', 'second'],
 },
'name2': {'details': ['other details'],
  'groups': ['first', 'third'],
 }}

counted = {}
for names in d.keys():
    for elements in d[names]["groups"]:
        if elements not in counted.keys():
            counted[elements] = 1
        else:
            counted[elements] += 1

print(counted)
```